# string validation over regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

How to validate the given string over the regular expression (XSD Pattern):

> xsd pattern:'([a-zA-Z0-9.,;:'+-/()?*[]{}\`´~
>   ]|[!"#%&<>÷=@_$£]|[àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ])*'

I need to validate the string with above pattern whether it matches or not.

I have tried the below code but getting unsupported escape characters error while compiling

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternMatching {
     private static Pattern usrNamePtrn = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9\.,;:'\+\-/\(\)?\*\[\]\{\}\\`´~ ]|[!"#%&<>÷=@_$£]|[àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ])*");

    public static boolean validateUserName(String userName){

        Matcher mtch = usrNamePtrn.matcher(userName);
        if(mtch.matches()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.out.println("Is a valid username?"+validateUserName("stephen & john"));

    }
}
```

how to do the above task, in addition to that if the doesn't match with the pattern then that characters need to be displayed.and I am using java 1.6 any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: You'll have to replace *"* with *\"*

Comment: can u provide some code snippet . i am not getting where i have to change " with \"

Comment: It's not ** but `"` which is causing the issue. Check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

### First, the regular expression itself has three mistakes.

*Mistake 1:*

A backslash is a special character which is used to escape whatever character follows it.  Therefore, the sequence

```
\`
```

is either identical to a single back-quote, or, depending on the regular expression engine, is an illegal escape sequence.  Either way, if the intent was to match a backslash along with all the other characters, it should be written as:

```
\\`
```

*Mistake 2:*

Inside the `[`…`]` character grouping, a `]` must be escaped so it doesn’t signify the end of the grouping.  So, `[]` needs to be written as `[\]`.

*Mistake 3:*

Inside the `[`…`]` character grouping, a `-` indicates a character range, like `a-z`.  The regular expression `[+-/]` does not mean “plus or hyphen or slash”;  it means “any of the characters between plus and slash, inclusive.”  Technically, this mistake doesn’t affect the outcome in this particular case, because `+-/` is equivalent to those three literal characters plus the comma and period, which both happen to occur earlier in the character grouping anyway.  But, in the interest of saying what you mean, the `-` should be escaped:

```
+\-/
```

### Second is the matter of turning the regular expression into a Java string.

The backslash and the double-quote are special characters in Java.  Obviously, `"` denotes the start and end of a String literal, so if you want a `"` inside a String, you must escape it:

```
\"
```

This is not related to regular expressions;  this just tells the compiler that the String contains a double-quote character.  It will be compiled into a single `"` and that is what the regular expression engine will see.

Finally, there is the matter of backslashes.  It just so happens that, while regular expressions use a backslash to escape characters as described above, Java also uses backslashes to escape characters in strings.  This means that if you want a literal backslash in a Java String, it must be written in the code as two backslashes:

```
String s = "\\";     // a String of length 1
```

Recall from above that we need a regular expression with consecutive backslash characters:

```
\\`
```

A Java string containing those three characters would look like this:

```
String s = "\\\\`";      // a String of length 3
```

A regular expression allows a backslash almost anywhere;  for instance, `\%` is the same as `%`.  However, [Java only allows specific characters to be preceded by a single backslash.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)  `\+` is not one of those permitted sequences.

`+`, `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}` are not special characters inside a `[`…`]` grouping, so there is no need to escape them anyway.

So, your code needs to be changed from this:

```
private static Pattern usrNamePtrn = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9\.,;:'\+\-/\(\)?\*\[\]\{\}\\`´~ ]|[!"#%&<>÷=@_$£]|[àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ])*");
```

to this:

```
private static Pattern usrNamePtrn = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9.,;:'+\\-/()?*\\[\\]{}\\\\`´~ ]|[!\"#%&<>÷=@_$£]|[àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ])*");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `"` is a special character in Java.

You'll have to substitute `"` with an escape character i.e. `\"` and `\` with `\\` as follows:

```
private static Pattern usrNamePtrn = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9.,;:'+-/()?*[]{}\\`´~ ]|[!\"#%&<>÷=@_$£]|[àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ])*");
```

Note the change in the pattern below where `"` and `\` have been replaced by `\"` and `\\`:

[image: Change(s)]

Also, note that this will only fix the Compile Issues. You need to re-check your Regex to see if it works fine.

Comment: This won’t compile.  You’re correct about the `"` character, but the first character range has two problems:  an unescaped hyphen, and a single backslash preceding a back-quote.

Comment: @VGR Thanks! I just realized that there are other issues with this Regex as it has `(` and `)` etc. which carries special meaning in Regex and hence will give errors if not preceded by the escape characters. I have Edited the answer. Thanks for spotting it out.

Comment: To specify a regex backslash literal, you need **four** backslashes - escaped once for java, and once again for regex.

Comment: i have used the regular expression suggested by "VGR" .no compilation issues but  when given a string like this having & in it (      Hofer &  Santoro) the output is a valid string.but if i send the same name in  XML it is validated over the same pattern i have mentioned above its throwing error entity reference is missing some thing like that.then i have replaced & with &amp then no issues. why the validations are different in two cases and how to send the strings with & in XML as it is because if add some thing to the name it will looks odd.any suggestions on this?